# How to keep metadata for recurring series master, even when the user changes 'this and the following' event? (extended properties / open extensions)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I want to use Microsoft Graph [open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) or [extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to store meta-data for recurring event series. Or more specifically for the master of the series.

I was able to store the property, however when the user changes the series (e.g. start time of event) and saves the series for 'this and the following' event, the system creates a new master with new id, and the problem is that this new master does not contain the custom property anymore.

I tried both open extensions and extended properties.

Is this the expected behaviour?

How can we store metadata to a series master, without loosing it when the user changes the series (e.g. time changed) and saves the event for 'this and the following'?

Comment: I tried extended properties/custom MAPI properties and it worked for me. If its not i tried the following business logic in my earlier scenario - make sure it contains the properties or not, if not stamp it back. Please note that the extended properties might be dropped if the receiver has any other addin or application at their server/client which might be dropping it. Please cross the incoming mailflow with help of your exchange administrator and see if it exists or not.

Comment: Hi @Dev - what do you mean by 'it worked for me'? Did the extended property get copied, when the user changed the time of the recurring event and then saved "this and the following"? Note: when changing time and saving 'this and the following' the system creates a new series master.